# Finding exact value with synonym applied in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have synonym set up for certain fields, however I would like it to be applied to fields I map to `not_analyzed`.

For example I have field `foo` storing `seksyen 10` which is `not_analyzed`, and a synonym entry is added for `seksyen, section` (dealing with mixed languages within a document).

```
'foo': {'type': 'string', 'index': 'not_analyzed'}
```

Suppose user issue a query

```
{"term": {"foo": "section 10"}}
```

and is expecting `foo` with `seksyen 10` and `section 10`. However, with the current mapping I can't return `seksyen 10` given the query. Also I am doing a filtered query here because I don't want these to be returned

```
whatever seksyen 10
seksyen 10, something
whatever section 10 something
```

I just want synonym expansion to be applied to the query, without it specified in the query. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using `term` will not do any analysis on the searched text, so you need a different type of query.

You can do it like the following:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "search_analyzer": "synonym"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "synonym": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "synonym"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "seksyen, section"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, you define a `search_analyzer` to be used at search time only. And then you need to give up on `term` filter otherwise it will not work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "foo": "section"
    }
  }
}
```

The solution above works in ES 1.x. In ES 2.x the `search_analyzer` and a `not_analyzed` field will not be possible anymore.

Comment: unfortunately I am on ES2.3 S: